# Can I decently program for the IPhone on the Mac Mini?

Tags: iphone

Our company is buying me a mac and essentially it is up to me to get what i want.
Will the MAC mini be adequate? I already have 2 22 inch monitors that can possibly hook up to the Mini.

Comment: Wouldn't you just want to get the best machine you possibly can rather then just settling for what is adequate?

Comment: Yes, entirely adequate. If you can get what you want, though, get a MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a mac mini will be fine for iphone development, but it really just depends what kinda of development. If you are going to be making 3d games using something like Unity or making all of your graphics in Photoshop then you really should upgrade to something more powerful, but for a basic iPhone application then you will be fine.

If you can you should probably get a Mac Pro. They are expensive, but they will last you many more years then a Mac Mini. It is the only computer that I have owned that I felt like I still had a powerful machine after 3 years.

If you use the mini for basic iPhone programming then you will just be waiting longer for the application to compile and XCode can feel unresponsive at times.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  That's what my last client did.  Bought the cheapest Intel Mac Mini available, and hooked it up to an existing PC monitor.  Performed well even for a very large iPhone project (several 100's of source files).

Answer (score 1):

In a word, yes. Mac minis are quite powerful given their size. But for a few bucks extra, I'd go the iMac simply because it's a complete package. Make sure you get 4G of RAM.

Comment: yes that is correct however I already have 2 22 inch monitors that can possibly hook up to the Mini. Sorry should have mentioned that above.